# Difficulty in ostream

Tags: c++, ostream

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const PT& p)
{
   os << "(" << p.x << "," << p.y << ")";
}
```

`PT` is a structure and `x` , `y` are its members.
Can someone please explain what exactly the above line does. Can't the desired text be printed using `cout`?

I came across this snippet of code from [this site](http://stanford.edu/~liszt90/acm/notebook.html#file8).

Comment: Well, first of al this code contains a bug. :-(

Comment: What is the bug ? - return os is missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This provides a method of outputting the PT. Now, you can use this:

```
PT p;
std::cout << p;
```

This gets translated into a call of

```
operator<< (std::cout, p);
```

That matches your overload, so it works, printing the x and y values in brackets with less effort on the user's part. In fact, it doesn't have to be `cout`. It can be anything that "is" a `std::ostream`. There are quite a few things that inherit from it, meaning they are `std::ostream`s as well, and so this works with them too. `std::ofstream`, for file I/O, is one example.

One thing that the sample you found doesn't do, but should, though, is `return os;`. Without doing that, you can't say `std::cout << p << '\n';` because the result of printing `p` will not return `cout` for you to use to print the newline.

Comment: Do you mean instead of writing this   -  ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const PT &p) { os << "(" << p.x << "," << p.y << ")";   we can write this - std::cout << p

Comment: @user1460207, You're overloading `operator<<`. Normally, when you say `std::cout << p;`, it will have no idea how to output the `PT`. Now you're telling it that it should print `"(" + pt.x + "," + pt.y + ")"` whenever it tries to print a `PT`. Otherwise, you'd have to format all of the statements you use to output the `PT` like that one, which is very redundant.

Answer (score 4):

It's a [custom overload](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html) for `operator<<`.

It means you can do this:

```
PT p = ...;
std::cout << p << "\n";
```

or this:

```
PT p = ...;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << p << "\n";
std::cout << ss;
```

or lots of other useful stuff.

However, it should be noted that the code you quoted won't work properly.  It needs to return `os`.

Comment: Why is it needed to write this line : std::cout << ss

Comment: What is it the reason for it to return os ?

Comment: @user1460207, This has nothing to do with the `cout << ss`. That one is taken care of because `std::stringstream` already did what you're doing here. The part of interest is `ss << p`, where instead of `cout` as the `ostream &`, you're passing it `ss`. It's proving it works on more than just `cout`. As for returning, it's so you can cascade the calls: `cout << p1 << ' ' << p2;`. You'll need back the `cout` to output the things after p1.

Answer (score 0):

It allows the << operator to append the PT object to the stream. It seems the object has elements x and y that are added with a comma separator.

Answer (score 0):

This operator **<<** overloading for outputing object of PT class .

Here:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const PT& p)
```

First param is for output stream where **p** will be appended.
It returns *reference* to **os** for chaining like this:

```
cout << pt << " it was pt" << endl;
```